# How do I use specific filter hook for LearnDash WooCommerce plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, wordpress-hook

The following code has been supplied through the LearnDash WooCommerce integration plugin.

It creates a filter which makes it able to disable removing people from courses after the billing cycle is complete. I want to turn this on by default, so that users aren't removed from their course anymore.

How can I apply this filter, without changing the plugin code?

```php
 /**
 * Get setting if course access should be removed when user completeng subscription payment billing cycle
 *
 * @param  object $subscription WC_Subscription object
 * @return boolean
 */
public static function is_course_access_removed_on_subscription_billing_cycle_completion( $subscription )
{
    return apply_filters( 'learndash_woocommerce_remove_course_access_on_subscription_billing_cycle_completion', false, $subscription );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```php
function my_callback_function ( $access, $subscription ) {
    $access = true;
    return $access;
}
add_filter( 'learndash_woocommerce_remove_course_access_on_subscription_billing_cycle_completion', 'my_callback_function', 10, 2 );
```

---

Related/Source: [`apply_filters( string $tag, mixed $value )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) - Calls the callback functions that have been added to a filter hook.

Example usage:

```php
// The filter callback function.
function example_callback( $string, $arg1, $arg2 ) {
    // (maybe) modify $string.
    return $string;
}
add_filter( 'example_filter', 'example_callback', 10, 3 );

/*
 * Apply the filters by calling the 'example_callback()' function
 * that's hooked onto `example_filter` above.
 *
 * - 'example_filter' is the filter hook.
 * - 'filter me' is the value being filtered.
 * - $arg1 and $arg2 are the additional arguments passed to the callback.
 */
$value = apply_filters( 'example_filter', 'filter me', $arg1, $arg2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hook the [WordPess `__return_false`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__return_false/) function with this filter hook, to disable removing people from courses after the billing cycle is complete, this way:

```
add_filter( 'learndash_woocommerce_remove_course_access_on_subscription_billing_cycle_completion', '__return_false' );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active theme). It should work.